# R installation issue libquadmath.so.0

Tags: r, shared-libraries, rhel

I have encountered issues in running R.

> /installables/R-3.1.3/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libquadmath.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Could anybody help here, as what is main package required to install which covers this libquadmath package.

Comment: When asking for this kind of info it's helpful to tell us about what OS you're running

Comment: What operating system are you using? And how did you install R in the first place?

Comment: Extremely sorry for that... I am using RHEL 6.5.

Comment: This is not connected to internet. So, to install R, i downloaded the R source code from one of AWS machine, configure --enable-R-shlib and make. Then I compressed the file and copied this to local machine. This local machine has its own local RHEL repository, hence i installed all the required packages like libX11, libX11-devel, libXt, libXt-devel.So when I use the untar R-3.1.3 file, I am getting the above exception. Hope this helps.